# Incomplete type is not allowed in my function call

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

I am getting an error in my code when trying to call a function. I have tried this a few different ways, but I just can't get it to work and I know it must be something stupid.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void openFile(string input);

int main()
{
    string input;
    cout << "Please enter a file to open: " << endl;
    cin >> input;

    void openFile(input);  //error is right here!!!!!!!!!

    return 0;
}



void openFile(string input) {

    ifstream in_file;

    in_file.open(input);
    if (in_file.fail())
        cout <<  "Something went wrong, file did not open!!!" << endl;
    else {
        cout << "File opened successfully!!!" << endl;
        cout << in_file.rdbuf() << endl;
    }
    in_file.close();
}
```

Comment: Have you given \\ double backslashes while giving the path, instead of single one ?

Comment: Voting to close as typo: That's not how you call a function.

Comment: Whoo I didn't pay attention to that, yes he didn't get the syntax right

Comment: @Jeremy Mahan you shouldn't write a void for calling a function.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't write a void for calling a function it's a return type used for functions prototype or deceleration. Below is correct code.

```
int main()
{
    string input;
    cout << "Please enter a file to open: " << endl;
    cin >> input;

    openFile(input); // function calls must not be preceded with a void keyword 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is always something stupid that I miss....